# "Object expected" error using jQuery only in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm getting an error only in IE (v8, I don't know if it happens in older IE versions, but it does not occur in Chrome or Firefox) which brings me the following message when I use IE dev tool's debbuger:

```
Breaking on JSScript runtime error - Object Expected
```

Here is my affected code:

```
$('#deviceProfileSelection').change(function() { //affected line!!!!
// rest of my code...
});
```

This element `#deviceProfileSelection` is defined as the following:

```
<select id="deviceProfileSelection">
   <option value=""><?php echo getSysMessage("dropDownSelect")?></option>
   <!-- and other values...-->
</select>
```

I've already tried defining the .change listener into a `$(document).ready(function () {});` but no success at all. Any other idea?

**EDIT**

I was trying to include a div using a PHP decision structure, where if a condition was true, it should print a div. But, actually it wasn't printing, I mean, it wasn't printing the opening tag 'div', only the closing tag 'div'.

The browsers could interpret this error, but IE8, and this IE inability was causing the issue.

Comment: do you have jQuery included on the page before attempting to call `$`?

Comment: What version jQuery are you using?

Comment: please note that jQuery v2.x does not support IE8. If you have jQuery v2, you will need to use v1.x instead.

Comment: Could you show the code that is inside this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't added jQuery into your code at all. 
Add the following inside the `<head>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

That should fix your problem.

Comment: OMG, it works perfectly! 

I was trying to include a div using a php decision structure where if a condition was true, it should print a div. But, actually it wasn't printing, I mean, it wasn't printing the opening tag 'div', only the closing tag 'div'.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox ignore this "unopened" div and that's why I couldn't see the error.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

1. Is jQuery included when this code is executed? (I'd do an alert on `$` and see what you get)
2. Make sure the `deviceProfileSection` element exists.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue to this before with IE8, if it's the same issue, it can't find the jquery library, check your path or test it with a cdn

Comment: No, surely it is already included. I can use other elements normally.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following code in IE8, and it works just as expected. As suggested in other answers, I used the latest version of JQuery that is compatible with IE8 from the JQuery CDN. Don't use 2.x -- it does not work with older browsers. Also, make sure your change event code is located in a document.ready handler.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>IE8 Object Expected</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $("#deviceProfileSelection").change(function(){
                    console.log("#deviceProfileSelection changed to " + $(this).find(":selected").text());
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <select id="deviceProfileSelection">
                <option value="">Select...</option>
                <option value="1">One</option>
                <option value="2">Two</option>
                <option value="3">Three</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just so that no one repeats my mistake, since you are using jquery from an external website( src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"), make sure your internet is working